# Convert Ansible variable from Unicode to ASCII

Tags: unicode, ansible

I'm getting the output of a command on the remote system and storing it in a variable.  It is then used to fill in a file template which gets placed on the system.

```
- name: Retrieve Initiator Name
  command: /usr/sbin/iscsi-iname
  register: iscsiname

- name: Setup InitiatorName File
  template: src=initiatorname.iscsi.template dest=/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
```

The initiatorname.iscsi.template file contains:

```
InitiatorName={{ iscsiname.stdout_lines }}
```

When I run it however, I get a file with the following:

```
InitiatorName=[u'iqn.2005-03.org.open-iscsi:2bb08ec8f94']
```

What I want:

```
InitiatorName=iqn.2005-03.org.open-iscsi:2bb08ec8f94
```

What am I doing wrong?

I realize I could write this to the file with an "echo "InitiatorName=$(/usr/sbin/iscsi-iname)" > /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi" but that seems like an un-Ansible way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The square brackets mean what you have is a list. You could try `stdout_lines[0]` if you only want the first line in the list.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I should've clue in that it was python.

Answer (score 13):

FWIW, if you really do have an array:

```
[u'string1', u'string2', u'string3']
```

And you want your template/whatever result to be NOT:

```
ABC=[u'string1', u'string2', u'string3']
```

But you prefer:

```
ABC=["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

Then, this will do the trick:

```
ABC=["{{ iscsiname.stdout_lines | list | join("\", \"") }}"]
```

(extra backslashes due to my code being in a string originally.)

Comment: Slight typo, should be: `ABC=["{{ iscsiname.stdout_lines | list | join("\", \"") }}"]`

Answer (score 12):

Use a filter to avoid unicode strings:

```
InitiatorName = {{ iscsiname.stdout_lines | to_yaml }}
```

[Ansible Playbook Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html)

Comment: This does fix the issue, but masks the actual problem, which is that the input is an array, not a string.

Comment: Beware. 

Per ansible doc:

`to_yaml and to_nice_yaml filters use PyYAML library which has a default 80 symbol string length limit. That causes unexpected line break after 80th symbol (if there is a space after 80th symbol) To avoid such behaviour and generate long lines it is possible to use width option:`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the 80 symbol limit of PyYAML, just use the `to_json` filter instead:

```
InitiatorName = {{ iscsiname.stdout_lines | to_yaml }}
```

In my case, I'd like to create a python array from a comma seperated list. So `a,b,c` should become `["a", "b", "c"]`.  But without the `'u'` prefix because I need string comparisations (without special chars) from WebSpher. Since they seems not to have the same encoding, comparisation fails. For this reason, I can't simply use `var.split(',')`.

Since the strings contains no special chars, I just use `to_json` in combination with `map(trim)`. This fixes the problem that `a, b` would become `"a", " b"`.

```
restartApps = {{ apps.split(',') | map('trim') | list | to_json }}
```

Since JSON also knows arrays, I get the same result than python would generate, but without the `u` prefix.