# How to convert a iterate loop list into a string to use in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

#### I have Ansible role that I want to iterate over.

The goal is to create new user accounts from a list.  The playbook calls the role and sends the list to iterate.

The OS (Linux Debian 8.8) sees the all of var unicode "[u'user']"

Some other tests performed show new users: 
['test']
[u'test']

All I really want is to have the var to be a string so I make a new user and add the needed keys and other files.  I can also join the var into paths for key and other files.

I have searched for an easy way to "| to_string", (not in Ansible)
The Filter "to_yaml" gets rid of the unicode but not "[]" and adds "\n" at the end.

The item for the ssh key copy if for the various id_(type).pub files.

#### I have read:

[Convert Ansible variable from Unicode to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413613/convert-ansible-variable-from-unicode-to-ascii)

#### Code

```
Playbook:

  vars_files:
    - /home/admin/common/vars/UserList 

  gather_facts: False

  roles:
    - { role: common, "{{ UserList }}" }
```

```
UserList file

---
UserList:
  - 'test'
...
```

```
role/common/main.yml 

---

  - name: Add user to server
    user:
      name: "{{ UserList }}"
      shell: /bin/bash

  - name: make direcotry
    file:
      path: "/home/{{ UserList }}/.ssh"
      state: directory

  - name: Copy ssh public key to user/.ssh/_key_.pub
    copy:
      src: "/home/{{ UserList }}/.ssh/{{ item }}"
      dest: "/home/{{ UserList }}/.ssh/{{ item }}"
      mode: 600
      force: no
    with_items:
      - id_rsa.pub
      - id_dsa.pub
      - id_ecdsa.pub
...
```

A different form, but still errored as below.

```
roles: 
  - role: common
  with_items: 
  - "{{ UserList }}"
```

#### Error

(item=id_rsa.pub) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"dest": "/home/[u'test']/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "force": false, "mode": 600, "src": "/home/[u'test']/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}, "module_name": "copy"}, "item": "id_rsa.pub", "msg": "could not find src=/home/[u'test']/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}

Comment: 'user' was an anomaly from another test run.  I re-ran with using test and updated the error message.

Comment: From     - { role: common, "{{ UserList }}" } to     -  role: common, "{{ UserList }}" ?   [ I do want to iterrate on more users].

Comment: I do see this snipit of code from the Docs:   `roles:
  - role: foo
    vars:
         message: "first"
  - { role: foo, vars: { message: "second" } }`  So should I set `-roles: \n  role: common \n vars: User: {{ UserList }} ` then in the role use {{ User }}?

Comment: Tried a differnet format for roles: `roles: \
    - role: common \
      with_items: \
      - "{{ UserList }}" ` No change I still get '[u'user']' as the var.  I also have tested with { Userlist } with no quotes and {} and still no effect.  Hmm.

Comment: Richard, please don't add code in the comments, as it's impossible to read; please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56359441/edit) to update it

Comment: I also don't understand your question: you know the variable is a **list** and you know you need to iterate over it, and yet you are asking about ascii and removing characters from the string representation of a list, when you haven't read [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)?

Comment: I am using this list as the source for the user names.  I then (with the script) create new users and copy the needed file to the new system.  I want to insert the current list element into a Linux path,

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

I found a workarount for my issue.  I would be cautious to call it a solution.  For this case it will suffice.  I need to "loop" with my var with the builtin {{ item }}.  Then {{ item }} is used as a string and I can create the PATHs I need.  I can also iterate through the a series of items with "with_nested".

```
  - name: create empty file
    file:
      path: "{{ '/home/' + item + '/.ssh/authorized_keys' }}"
      state: touch
    with_items:
      - "{{ UserList }}"


  - name: Copy ssh public key to user/.ssh/_key_.pub
    copy:
      src: "{{ '/home/' + item[1] + '/.ssh/' + item[0] }}"
      dest: "{{ '/home/' + item[1] + '/.ssh/' + item[0] }}"
      mode: 600
      force: no
    with_nested:
      - [ 'id_rsa.pub' , 'id_dsa.pub' , 'id_ecdsa.pub' ]
      - "{{ UserList }}"
```